# Are my hard drives encrypted?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, raid, lvm

New to Ubuntu Server, please forgive my ignorance.

When I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Alternative. I selected "Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM".

I now am adding two hard drives with RAID 1 configuration. Will these be encrypted by default or will I have to use LVM to encrypt them?

If I need to encrypt them, does anyone know of a good guide. I've been searching all over the web but only see guides for old versions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Additional drives will not be encrypted just because your root file system was encrypted during installation.  LVM is also not referring to encryption but logical volume management -- the encryption that Ubuntu uses is LUKS.  You can manage volumes and create partitions easily using the Disks application and you can also choose to encrypt.  However if you are setting up RAID, it will probably be done by your RAID controller or software.  How exactly do you plan to set up your RAID?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Nmath. I used mdadm to create the RAID configuration.

Comment: Once your RAID is set up it is treated as one volume.  The process to set up encryption is then exactly the same as any other drive.  The included [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks) app (gnome-disk-utility) is already included and straightforward, and gives you an option to set up LUKS encryption when creating a partition.  You could also use Veracrypt, KDE vault, etc, just like you would encrypt any other volume